# "Get Key Failed: Given final block not properly padded" when I try loading .p12 certificate in a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, keystore, pkcs#12

Specifically, the relevant part of the code looks like this (capitalized words are placeholders):

```
FileInputStream("PATH TO P12 FILE");

 KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "PKCS12" );

 keyStore.load( file_inputstream, "PASSWORD".toCharArray() );

 Key privatni = keyStore.getKey( "ALIAS", " PASSWORD ".toCharArray() );

 Signature biljeznik = Signature.getInstance( "SHA256withRSA" );

 biljeznik.initSign( ( PrivateKey )privatni );

 biljeznik.update( medjurezultat.getBytes() );

 potpisano = biljeznik.sign();
```

I am 100% sure that the password and the alias are correct. I am aware that P12 files can't have 2 passwords like JKS keystores, but I'm not sure how to change the code if that's the problem (the only password is written under both "PASSWORD" placeholders).

The exact error message is this one:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:91)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1050)
    at primjer.ZastitniKodIzracun.main(ZastitniKodIzracun.java:56)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:859)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:939)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:735)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:424)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:456)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.lambda$engineGetKey$0(PKCS12KeyStore.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore$RetryWithZero.run(PKCS12KeyStore.java:257)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:361)
    ... 3 more
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am 100% sure that the password and the alias are correct." How? Have you verified the keystore password with other code, for example using `keytool list` to list the entries of the keystore? Or something similar with OpenSSL?

Comment: @erickson I know because I work with these certificates a lot so I easily remember the password - and, as you recommend, I have verified it by using ```keystore list``` in Command Prompt (that's also how I checked the alias).

Comment: Then it almost certainly is a 'key' (entry) pw different from the store pw. `keytool` tries not to _create_ such a different pw but other Java code can and I'm not sure about `-importkeystore`, plus non-Java tools of course. `keytool list` only shows the certificate info and does not 'open' aka 'unwrap' the privatekey(s) (although it does indicate their existence in the type) which for PKCS12 means it decrypts the certbag but not the shroudedkeybag(s). Your program does need to 'open' the privatekey to do signing. By what procedure did you create this keystore?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the reply, my thoughts began to go somewhere in the same direction, too - unfortunately, I am not the creator of the keystore, as per Croatian law it is created for each business subject by the state Financial agency (the purpose of the project is the generation of a code needed to make possible the communication of the company with the Tax office information service).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 If it means anything: I've tried converting the .p12 file to .jks and adding two distinct password with ```deststorepass``` and ```destkeypass``` commands - the error I am now getting is "UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very dumb mistake:

```
keyStore.load( file_inputstream, "PASSWORD".toCharArray() );
Key privatni = keyStore.getKey( "ALIAS", " PASSWORD ".toCharArray() );
```

The spaces in the second PASSWORD were causing the error. It should be:

```
keyStore.load( file_inputstream, "PASSWORD".toCharArray() );
Key privatni = keyStore.getKey( "ALIAS", "PASSWORD".toCharArray() );
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue and I was fussing over the keystore file (which was working fine in a different application with a similar use). Your answer led me to check the password and there it was - a typo. Thank you for coming back and answering your own question - this saved my day though I feel so silly for not checking the password so far.